# Выровнять 3 блока по центру во flexbox контейнере

Tags: css, flexbox

Вот пример ([источник](https://codepen.io/alexmillern/pen/GRRjXWV)):

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  color: #37447e;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.header__logo:hover {
  color: #37447e;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu__items {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu__item {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.menu__item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.menu__item-link {
  color: #505f98;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.menu__item-link:hover {
  color: #505f98;
}

.btn {
  color: #091133;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #ffd166;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="header__nav">
      <ul class="menu__items">
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__item-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__item-link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__item-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__item-link" href="#">link link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a class="header__logo" href="#">Landie</a>
      <button class="btn">Purchase UI Kit</button>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Из примера можно заметить, что блок логотип смещается немного вправо. Можно конечно пофиксить это `position: absolute`, но вряд ли это решение будет правильным.

Как правильно выровнять центральный блок по центру?

Comment: `position: absolute` будет правильным решением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создадим обертку для кнопки справа

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
   <button class="btn">Purchase UI Kit</button>
</div>
```

Затем всем элементам флексбокса зададим `flex:1` и пропишем ориентацию внутри блока.

```
.header__logo
   flex: 1
   text-align: center
.menu__items
   flex: 1
.button-wrapper
    flex: 1
    text-align: right
```